# Universal Mapping Property of Free Categories

Tags: category-theory, functors, universal-property

Let $G$ be a graph. We say that a category $\textbf{C}$ has a universal mapping property of free categories on $G$ if there exists a graph homomorphism $i:G\longrightarrow |\textbf{C}|$ such that given any category $\textbf{D}$ and a graph homomorphism $h:G\longrightarrow |\textbf{D}|$, there exists a unique functor $F_{h}:\textbf{C}\longrightarrow \textbf{D}$ such that $|F_{h}|i=h$.

Did I understand this right? I'm reading Awodey's Category Theory, and the way he defines UMP is a nightmare.

Comment: Universal properties usually include *uniqueness* as well, this time it would be the uniqueness of the functor $F_h$. With that, we simply call $\bf C$ the *free category* over graph $G$.

Comment: @Berci yes, I forgot to emphasize the uniqueness part. But other than that, I hope that I wrote the UMP correct.

Comment: Yes, it's probably correct (though I'm not familiar with this book). Note that it should be exactly the same universal property as for the *free group* (or *free monoid*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Notice that this definition works for any functor $U : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$; here, it is the forgetful functor $U : \mathbf{Cat} \to \mathbf{Graph}$. The [$U$-free object](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/free+object) on $X \in \mathcal{D}$ is an object $A \in \mathcal{C}$ with a morphism $i : X \to U(A)$ such that for every morphism $h : X \to U(A')$ there is a unique morphism $f : A \to A'$ with $h = U(f) \circ i$. In other words, it is an initial object in the comma category $X \downarrow U$. This is sometimes also called a universal arrow to $U$. When every object of $\mathcal{D}$ has a universal arrow to $U$, then $U$ is a [right adjoint](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/right+adjoint). This is the case here.